# MySQL: Query table with distinct "action"

Tags: mysql

This is my current table:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| userid | action   | day        |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 123    | play     | 2016-11-06 |
| 123    | purchase | 2016-11-06 |
| 345    | login    | 2016-11-06 |
| 123    | level_up | 2016-11-07 |
| 123    | play     | 2016-10-01 |
| 456    | sign_out | 2016-10-02 |
| 456    | sign_out | 2016-11-02 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

I want to print out userid that has at least 2 unique actions.
456 only has 1 distinct, so I don't want to print it out.

So I want it print out:

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| userid | action   | day        |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 123    | play     | 2016-11-06 |
| 123    | purchase | 2016-11-06 | 
| 123    | level_up | 2016-11-07 |
| 123    | play     | 2016-10-01 | 
+--------+----------+------------+
```

This is my best attempt:

```
SELECT userid as this_id

FROM sampleTable WHERE (

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT action) 
     FROM sampletable
    WHERE userid = this_id) 
     >= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to count distinct `action` for each user first. Then with the help of `inner join` you could get the desired rows.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM your_table YT 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
     userid
    FROM your_table 
     --Add your where clause here 
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT action) >= 2
) AS t
ON t.userid = YT.userid;
```

---

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM your_table YT 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
     userid
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE action IN ('play', 'level_up')
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT action) = 2
) AS t
ON t.userid = YT.userid;
```

Comment: Any chance u could make it more simple :) because i also have to add to where only if userid contains both 'play' and 'level_up'.

Comment: I can add different version of the above query using `EXISTS/IN` but this won't make the query simpler. What's your issue with adding a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Do you know how to join this statement?

Comment: I've mentioned in the query where you can add `where` clause

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT action, userid
FROM SampleTable as t1
WHERE userid IN
    (SELECT userid
     FROM SampleTable
     WHERE action IN ('play', 'level_up'));

Comment: Then what's the problem with the first query??

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT action) = 2` should be applicable where you want only users who have exactly two distinct actions provided in the `where` clause.